# using /deep/ in angular 4 componet.css causes other components to use the same style. How to solve it?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular, angular-material2

Note: I use css with angular4 not scss.

to be more specific,

my number.component.css has,

`/deep/ .mat-drawer-content{
 height:100vh;
}`

other component.css has doesn't has **.mat-drawer-content** class but it is common to all the views. It generated by angular-material2.

Problem is when i route to number.component and check all the other components also get **height:100vh;** so it causes my views to break. For now only solution I have is to remove the style parts with /deep/ and go for another solution.

If anyone knows how to keep that style only to that component please tell me.

(only css with **/deep/** causes this issue)

[You can see it here reproduced](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfczev?file=app%2Fheader%2Fheader.component.html) only used height for demonstration purpose.

Comment: Can you reproduce in http://stackblitz.com? It shouldn't apply to elements that don't have the class `mat-drawer-content`

Comment: Isn't /deep/ deprecated ?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't really matter. `::ng-deep` is the replacement, but that's also deprecated. As far as I know this is because basically `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` (currently default) is deprecated and will be replaced by  `ViewEncapsulation.Native` when all supported browsers properly support it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yeah it should not. But I guess /deep/ causes it, because it breaks css encapsulation. I will try to reproduce in stackblitz.com

Comment: @trichetriche yeah it is, I don't know any other way to do it without /deep/.

Comment: There isn't really another way. It's best to just ignore that it is deprecated. I think it was a very weird decision to deprecate it, especially to deprecate `::ng-deep` at the same time it was introduced.

Comment: WSell you can ignore it, but IE throws an error if you use it so ... Not the best practice !

Comment: That's quite unlikely, because Angular will never pass it to the DOM, it rewrites the styles to something different before it adds them to the DOM, so IE won't throw an error for it.

Comment: @trichetriche as far as I know IE also old -.- . Edge also throws an error?

Comment: Don't know, just remember I was having an issue with it

Comment: You only get an error when you add `/deep/` or `::ng-deep` to CSS that is not handled by Angular (CSS added directly to `index.html`).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer you can see my problem here. I reproduced it.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfczev?file=app%2Fheader%2Fheader.component.html

Comment: Only `<p>` elements are colored red. Not sure what you expect. There is no class involved like in your question.

Comment: I only applied red in header.component so it should not apply to footer.component. but it applied to footer <p> also when i go back from header to footer

Answer (score 1):

**update**

`::slotted` is now supported by all new browsers and can be used with `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted

**original**

I guess what you want is

```
:host /deep/ p{
  color:red;
}
```

or better

```
:host ::ng-deep p{
  color:red;
}
```

[**StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eeesja)

If you want to style the child depending on the class of a parent, you can use

```
:host-context(.mat-drawer-content) /deep/ p {
  color:red;
}
```

[**StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sc8cka?file=app/header/header.component.css)

Comment: yo there is a another problem. I can give you a +1 because it solves half of the problem it still doesn't solves the whole problem. because when I apply it doesn't apply to dynamically generated classes like .mat-drawer-content.

Comment: Please try to make a reproduction in stackblitz. "doesn't apply to dynamically generated classes like .mat-drawer-content." isn't a lot of information.

Comment: yeah gimme few minutes.

Comment: check the the Stackblitz now. I replaced it wit what exactly i want .mat-drawer-content. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfczev?file=app%2Fheader%2Fheader.component.html

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: same as the <p> tag before it should apply red only into header.component. Not to footer.component also. only want to do it by changing .mat-drawer-content

Comment: It still not applying to .mat-drawer-content class. you can inspect it and see. try changing .mat-drawer-content height instead of color of all the content.

Comment: What element should get the height? The element with the `.mat-drawer-content` class (the parent/ancestor of the header component)?

Comment: .mat-drawer-content class should get the height not child elements.

Comment: But only when the child is the header component? I doubt this can be done with CSS alone

Comment: Yeah I doubt that too. I will have to change the way I code maybe.

Comment: You can add a directive to `<mat-sidenav-content>` and use a shared service (provided on the directive, injected in `header`) and communicate to the directive if it should add an additional class or remove it. Then you can just add the style to `index.html` with a selector matching the class added by the directive.

Comment: well I wil try it. But mat-sidenav-content is a material directive. Isn't it a problem?

Comment: Why would it be a problem? You can add a directive everywhere. The directive only needs to add/remove a class on the element where it's added

Answer (score 0):

Went so close with Gunter's answer and still couldn't resolve it. To resolve I changed the way I styled my app so it won't be a problem.